# Owncloud + Swift + Keystone

Tags: keystone

I need this information fast, so please help me.
I wanna know if I can access OpenStack Swift on Owncloud applicaton using keystone as the method of authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

See if this ownCloud doc helps.
http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/admin_manual/configuration/custom_mount_config.html

I would advice you to look at [ownCloud discussion forum](http://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=9092) for more help.

Good luck!!